# Accessing libgdx classes within Android classes

Tags: android, libgdx

Currently what I'm able to do is to access android APIs within libgdx with an  interface in core and defining all the methods and then implementing it in every project (desktop, android, etc). What I want to do is I want to create a way so that I can call a method from some android class (say AndroidLauncher) and it calls a method of a libgdx core project class (like modifying some stage element). How do go about that?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Note: As a 'hack' right now, I'm just waiting for any update from android class in the render method using those same interface methods, but I don't think that's the best possible way.